Javascript Object Field Changing Unintentionally with setState?
For the life of me, I cannot figure this one out. I have a state variable, counties, which was initialized like this:
const [counties, setCounties] = useState(new Set([]))
I have a function which pulls a list of counties associated with a state. In my UI, the user can select a state field, and I want to populate a Select Dropdown with county values. I populate them using a useEffect function with state as a dependency as shown below.
    useEffect(() => {
        const getCounties = async () => {
            try {
                console.log("Fetching...")
                const response = await fetch(`/api/prospects/getCounties/?state=${state}`);
                const data = await response.json();
                
                // Ensure deep cloning to avoid unintended mutations
                const regionsSection = {
                    section: "Regions",
                    values: [...data[0].values]
                };
                const countiesSection = {
                    section: "Counties",
                    values: [...data[1].values]
                };

                console.log('Regions section:', regionsSection);
                console.log('Counties section:', countiesSection);

                // Set the state with the deep cloned sections
                setCounties([regionsSection, countiesSection]);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching counties:', error);
            }
        }

        getCounties();
    }, [state])

Now, here is where it gets bizarre. You can see that in the top level array, there is an array containing only two objects. One has a section variable titled "Regions", the other "Counties".
When this portion is run:
const countiesSection = {
    section: "Counties",
    values: [...data[1].values]
};


The section field is being updated to the string in the last element of the data[1].values array. So, instead of saying "Counties", it says, "X County".
Even weirder, this is corrected when I delete the setState function which appears AFTER this line of code. When I delete it, then the output is pasted correctly with "Counties" appearing in the section value.
I would appreciate any help here. I have spent four hours staring at a screen unable to understand what is going on.

What is state? Where does it come from?

state is also a useState variable controlled by a text input field. That value coming from state is accurate.

If it comes from using useState and it is attached to a text change event you might want to throttle/debounce the event, so the useEffect isn't triggered too many times within a timeframe since state is passed as dependency to the effect.
A suggestion: I don't know how you use the counties state but I think it is better to have that state be a map or object type instead of an array type.
